# Exploding based on \n

Tags: php, csv

I'm pulling in a CSV and I want to explode the returned string based on the new line.

```
$quotes = file_get_contents('http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CLQ12.NYM+NGQ12.NYM+GCQ12.CMX+SIN12.CMX+HGN12.CMX+^DJI+^GSPC+^GSPTSE+^SPCDNX+X&f=nsc1');
```

Gives me:

```
"Crude Oil Aug 12","CLQ12.NYM",-3.10
"Natural Gas Aug 1","NGQ12.NYM",-0.165
"Gold Aug 12","GCQ12.CMX",-28.40
"Silver Jul 12","SIN12.CMX",-0.698
"Copper Jul 12","HGN12.CMX",-0.079
"S&P 500","^GSPC",-13.20
"S&P/TSX Composite","^GSPTSE",-156.71
"S&P/TSX Venture C","^SPCDNX",-18.29
"United States Ste","X",-0.37
```

However, using  `$quotes = explode('\n', $quotes);` doesn't do anything. Whats the easiest way to return an array of every line?

Answer (score 8):

You need double quotes, otherwise PHP won't parse escape sequences:

```
$quotes = explode("\n", $quotes);
```

You could also use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to return an array of the lines:

```
$array = file( 'http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CLQ12.NYM+NGQ12.NYM+GCQ12.CMX+SIN12.CMX+HGN12.CMX+^DJI+^GSPC+^GSPTSE+^SPCDNX+X&f=nsc1');
```

However, a better approach might be the CSV functions built into PHP, such as [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv).

Comment: I was going to say ... but yeah, indeed. +1

Comment: "If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters" http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using fgetcsv.

It'll retrieve row by row as an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use PHP_EOL for cross-OS compatibility:

```
<?php
$quotes = file_get_contents('http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CLQ12.NYM+NGQ12.NYM+GCQ12.CMX+SIN12.CMX+HGN12.CMX+^DJI+^GSPC+^GSPTSE+^SPCDNX+X&f=nsc1');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $quotes);
?>
```